# Best way of initialize multi-page jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

This is a bit confusing so I'd like to know what the correct way is nowadays, for initialize your multi-page app.

```
<head>
// include multiple JS files

<script>

// page init   

</script>
</head>
```

For page init i've tried:

```
$(function() {

// or 
$("div[data-role='page']").on("pagecreate", function() {


// or
$(document).on("pagecreate", function() {
```

I've noticed that the include JS files are all "run" before the page init. And calling a function in "page init" from a JS-file isn't possible... Right now they all look like:

```
// ab.js

function a() {}

function b() {}

// so on
```

Should all functions in the JS files also be inside some sort of init? Like:

```
// JS file ab.js
$(function()
{
    function a() {}
    function b() {}
});
```

This question might be a bit unclear, but I'm just confused, and since JQM changes all the time I'd like to know what the "best" way is today....

Comment: $("div[data-role='page']").on("pagecreate", function()
This was a complete fail. Nothing works now

Comment: `$(document)` not `$("#pageID")`. delegate event to page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to know the difference between jQuery Mobile 1.4 events; the ones that emit once on *page* and the ones emit continuously on *pagecontainer*.

To add listeners, e.g. `click`, `tap`, `change`...etc. Wrap them and their *custom* function in `pagecreate`. That event fires once per page, so you need to specify `#pageID` in order to add those *listeners* to that page only. If you fail to specify a page, those *listeners* will be added again and again whenever `pagecreate` is emitted on a page.

You can as well use `pagecreate` to manipulate DOM and inject elements dynamically.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () {
   <!-- listeners -->
});
```

To manipulate DOM whenever page is shown/hidden, you need to listen to *pagecontainer* events. Those events fire continuously on *pagecontainer*, thus, it isn't a good idea to add listeners here. Use them to add, remove, hide, show, reset...etc, however, the new *pagecontainer* events can't be attached to a specific `#pageID`. You'll need to check which page is active or which page is going to be hidden.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
  var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage"),
      activePageID = activePage[0].id;

  if (activePageId == "pageA") {
    $(elm1).hide();
    $(elm2).show();
  }
});
```

---

### Update

Usage of *Self-Executing Functions* `$(function () { });` is limited to specific cases in jQM. They are used to initialize widgets that can be used *externally*, i.e. Panels, Toolbars and Popup.

Code wrapped in `$(function () { });` will be executed as soon as it is loaded.

Comment: I have a specific js file for all listeners. That one is included in <head>. Also that js file starts with `$(function()` . My "main" html file starts with $(document).on("pagecreate"

Comment: @BakedInhalf when you wrap any function in `$(function(){});` it will run straight away once JS file is loaded. It's called [Self-Executing Functions](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/).

Comment: Ah ok. Well, seems to work for my listeners to be wrapped with that $(function(){});

Comment: @BakedInhalf they will work, but you're asking about best practice :)

Comment: I think I understand the difference now :-)